# Does headerdoc2html not generate an overall index/ToC?

Tags: xcode, xcode-tools

Does headerdoc2html not generate an overall index that lists all the classes in a ToC?  When I run this...

```
headerdoc2html -o ~/Desktop/DocTest MyProject
```

I end up with a subfolder for each class in DocTest (e.g., DocTest/class1, DocTest/class2).  Within each of those folders I see a toc.html and index.html but it only links to the single class in the folder.

Basically, rather than getting one to.html with all my classes I'm ending up with a folder per class, which doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I had missed the fact that gatherheaderdoc exists, that solves the problem I had